# Why is it better to use class name instead of objects to access class methods or variables in Java?

Tags: java, static-methods, static-members

I was reading Code Conventions for Java from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137265.html#587.

In that, they have mentioned that we should avoid the use of objects to access a class variable or a method and should we use the class name instead.

> Avoid using an object to access a class (static) variable or method.
>   Use a class name instead. For example:
>
> ```
> classMethod();             //OK 
> AClass.classMethod();      //OK
> anObject.classMethod();    //AVOID!
> ```

Is there a particular reason for this in terms or performance or something else?

Comment: Can you give us a code example of the preferred method vs the objcect based method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By class variables I assume you mean static variables.

The use of static variables/methods through instance variables should be avoided because it's confusing to the reader. Since you can only use instances to access instance variables, reading a code that calls static methods through an instance can confuse the reader about what's going on.

Image this case, with `Thread.sleep`, which is a static method:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Since the method is static and we are calling it through the class name, it's intuitive to the reader to deduce that the effect is to put the current thread to sleep.

Now if we did this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(...);
t.sleep(1000);
```

Now which thread is put to sleep? The current one "obviously". Someone not knowing about how sleep works might think that the child thread is somehow put to sleep.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it depends on what you want to do.I for one always use the class name to acces a static variable.Being static it doesn matter the way you do it, but i does save some memory usage.

As for nonstatic variables, always use objects.

Comment: Of course since you can't access nonstatic variable from Class

Comment: Exactly, i know it sounded a lot worse than i thought.I meant as for non static, of course use objects.Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

It is not any different in terms of the bytecode that's produced, so performance is not the issue.

What *is* the issue is that using a variable to access static members looks as if the reference held by the variable actually matters to what is being accessed. But it does not! In fact even if `anObject` where `null`, you would *not* get a `NPE`, but it would just call `classMethod`.

So the principle is simple: when accessing static members, avoid mentioning information (in this case the variable name) that's actually not relevant to the access being made.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about performance, but clearly another developper looking your code will know at first sight its a static variable/method if you use it with the classname.

I don't think compiler will give different code using a variable though.

Answer (score 1):

it's because.

1.It tells that the variable or method is a static actually.

2.Also, its checked that the object refers to which class. that incurs extra cost.